# How to calculate cumulative geometric mean?

Tags: python-3.x, math, real-time, finance

I'm looking to calculate cumulative geometric average, with O(1) space, where the input is a stream of unknown numbers. Batch = 1. I have this example that is close enough to the problem I'm trying to solve:

```
count = 1
geo_avg = 0
while True:
  number = input("Enter number: ")

  geo_avg = ((1 + float(number)) * (1 + geo_avg)) ** (1 / count) - 1

  print("current geometric average", geo_avg, "\n")

  count += 1
```

I know this is wrong. I think I may have to remove the previous geometric average and then calculate the current geometric average, but that doesn't sound right either. Any comments/hints on what is the right equation to use would be very useful.

Comment: keep track of the running sum of $\log$ of each value.  The geometric mean can be computed from that easily anytime you need it.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. Does this make sense? `ln_sum += ln(1 + number); geo_avg = e^((1/count) * ln_sum) - 1`

Comment: Idea of cummulative mean: `cumprod(x)**(1/range(1,len(x) + 1)` . So you could keep track of the product, ie have `prod =* float(number); geo_avg = prod**(1/count); count +=1`

Comment: @Loc, does code need to handle `geometric_averager(x)` where `x < 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep track of the logarithmic sum and the number count in order to compute the geometric mean as the arithmetic mean in logscale, as described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean).

Here's the Python implementation, using a closure.

```py
from math import log, exp


def make_geometric_averager():
    log_sum = 0
    number_count = 0

    def geometric_mean(x: float):
        nonlocal log_sum, number_count
        log_sum += log(x)
        number_count += 1
        return exp(log_sum / number_count)
    
    return geometric_mean


# Example
geometric_averager = make_geometric_averager()

print(geometric_averager(10))  # 10.0
print(geometric_averager(100))  # 31.62
print(geometric_averager(1000))  # 99.99, numerical imprecision
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the idea mentioned in the comments:

```
import math


def running_geo_mean(x):
    sum_log = 0
    count = 0
    mean = []
    for elem in x:
        sum_log += math.log(elem)
        count += 1
        mean.append(math.exp(sum_log / count))
    return mean
```

Example usage:

```
x = [i + 1 for i in range(10)]
print(running_geo_mean(x))
```

```
[1.0, 1.414213562373095, 1.8171205928321397, 2.213363839400643, 2.6051710846973517, 2.993795165523909, 3.3800151591412964, 3.764350599503129, 4.1471662743969135, 4.528728688116766]
```

Comment: This is just the `geometric_mean`.  The "running" implies that they are repeatedly computing this.  I.e. they have 20M values in a set.  They've computed the geometric mean at this point, then the code goes and does other things with that mean.  They now get an additional value (so 20,000,001 values), and need the geometric mean of that.  (and so on)

Comment: @Him It isn't, note how many values geometric mean returns versus how many values this implementation returns.

Comment: Sure, but the OP says they have a "stream", so the purpose of the "running" version is to not have to add up 20M things each time.  The 20M + 1 th mean is constant time if you cache the sum (in a class variable, or a global variable, or by doing this as a coroutine, or or or....

Comment: @Him I don't agree with your reading of the question. I invite you to leave an answer which implements your interpretation.

Comment: [See @NoeDuruz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77172681/2886575)

Comment: @Him I disagree with both of you! :)   Usually, a "running" average means that you slide of window of a certain size across the input, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average.

Comment: @TooTone this is fair, and is possibly what the OP is getting at.  In this case, it definitely makes sense to maintain the `deque` of values that you can `popleft` and `appendright` to, and, depending on the size of the window, you might want to still maintain this running sum of `$\log$`s.  However, if we're subtracting the left value each time, then the floating-point errors would definitely accumulate and would be worse than simply re-geomean-ing the list.  So the constant-time maintained tally might not be a good idea.

Comment: Appreciate the solution here and the discussion. This is partly my fault, I should have been clearer. It is true that I was trying to find a solution with O(1) space. And  "running" is not the right word, and now I see that I should have used cumulative geometric mean.

Answer (score 1):

If g_n is the geometric mean of n numbers, then to include another number x_{n+1}, the new geometric mean is

```
g_{n+1} = (x_{n+1} * ((g_n) ^ n)) ^ (1/(n+1))
```

This formula might introduce lots of rounding errors in practice though. If you keep the running product

```
(g_n) ^ n = prod{i = 1 to n} x_i = P_n
```

it should return better accuracy. If you have m numbers to include, x_{n+1},...,x_{n+m}, then calculate

```
p = prod_{i = n+1 to n+m} x_i
```

first and then

```
P_{n+m} = (p * P_n)

g_{n+m} = P_{n+m} ^ (1/(n+m))
```

If there is a danger of P_n overflowing, then you can instead sum the logs as suggested by Him. I would expect this to be slower and have in general, higher rounding errors, but much less likely to overflow.

```
L_n = sum_{i = 1 to n} ln(x_i) = n * ln(g_n)

g_n = exp(L_n/n)
```

Then for another m numbers, calculate

```
l = sum_{i = n+1 to n+m} ln(x_i)

L_{n+m} = l + L_n

g_{n+m} = exp(L_{n+m}/(n+m))
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate a running geometric mean of size `n`, you can keep track of the last `n` number, and the current product. When you have a new number, you divide out the number to be replaced, and multiply in the number to be added.

Here's one way of doing it in Python.

```
import functools
import math


def produce_geometric_average(n: int):
    lst = []
    log_prod = 0
    idx = 0

    def geometric_average(x: float):
        nonlocal lst
        nonlocal log_prod
        nonlocal idx
        log_x = math.log(x)
        if len(lst) < n:
            lst.append(log_x)
            log_prod = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, lst)
        else:
            idx_to_replace = idx % n
            old_log_x = lst[idx_to_replace]
            log_prod = log_prod - old_log_x + log_x
            lst[idx_to_replace] = log_x
        idx += 1
        return math.exp(log_prod / len(lst))
        # c.f., return math.exp(functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, lst) / len(lst))

    return geometric_average


geometric_average = produce_geometric_average(3)

for x in [1.0, 1.0, 8.0, 27.0, 64.0, 125.0, 216.0]:
    print(geometric_average(x))
```

Output

```
1.0
1.0
2.0
6.000000000000001 
23.999999999999993
59.999999999999986
119.99999999999997
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the individual numbers, the product will exceed the size of a `long` in short order.  For example, if the numbers are all `2`, then after the size of the set grows to `64`, the product will be too large to store in a `long`.  Of course, python is capable of representing arbitrarily large integers, but this representation has its limits, one of which is when doing things like `**`: Python will attempt to convert `prod` to a `float`, and will simply error if `prod` is too large.

Comment: @Him You're right. I'd meant to pass floats not ints to the function, but nevertheless, I'd assumed that size of double precision number, c. 10^300 is very large and would be sufficient, but for rolling geometric averages of several 100 numbers, this is an unreasonable assumption. Have fixed, thank you.

Comment: @Him although doing the "running" part of the geometric mean with a closure seems kind of stupid now I think about it, as the client likely already has a list / circular buffer / etc, and this answer creates another copy of it.

Comment: "kind of stupid" nah.  I would have done it with `RunningStatistics` class, maybe, or some such, but it's just another way to namespace variables /shrug.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually one-liner, given previous tuple of **(gm<sub>n</sub>, n)**, and new value **x**, return back new tuple of **(gm<sub>n+1</sub>, n+1)**

```
def update_geo_mean(gm_n, x):
    gm, n = gm_n
    return ((gm**n * x)**(1.0/(n+1)), n+1)
```

one could use exp/log to avoid overflow/underflow.

Start with (1,0) tuple

Version with log/exp

```
import numpy as np

def update_geo_mean(gm_n, x):
    gm, n = gm_n
    return (np.exp((n * np.log(gm) + np.log(x))/(n+1)), n+1)
```

UPDATE

One could think of tuple **(gm<sub>n</sub>, n)** and update_geo_mean() as example of [Monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) with identity element being **(1,0)** tuple. Monoid binary operation would be

```
def geo_mean_binary(gm_n, gm_m):
    g_n, n = gm_n
    g_m, m = gm_m

    return (np.exp((n * np.log(g_n) + m*np.log(g_m))/(n+m)), n+m)
```

and

```
def update_geo_mean(gm_n, x):
    return geo_mean_binary(gm_n, (x,1))
```